# Splitting a list in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am working my way into learning a bit of Scheme (actually, Racket) with the help of a few practical problems to solve. In this case, I want to split a flat list of symbols at a certain delimiter symbol, discarding it and returning the list of split chunks.

```
#! /usr/bin/racket

#lang racket

(define (split lst del)
    (define (split-one lst)
        (if (or (empty? lst) (equal? (car lst) del))
            '()
            (cons (car lst) (split-one (cdr lst)))))
    (let loop ((next lst))
        (if (empty? next)
            '()
            (let ((cur (split-one next)))
                (cons
                    cur
                    (loop (let ((nextpos (+ 1 (length cur))))
                        (if (< nextpos (length next))
                            (list-tail next nextpos)
                            '()))))))))

(split '(a b c x d x e x f) 'x) ; '((a b c) (d) (e) (f))
(split '(0 1 2 0 2 0 3 0) 0) ; '(() (1 2) (2) (3))
```

It does work, but I feel it's not the best way to accomplish the task, for a couple of reasons:

- The `(loop (let (...` part seems a bit clunky, maybe even unnecessary.
- The `(list-tail ...` clause entails rescanning the list for `nextpos` elements, which obviously is not optimal. In Python, I would have `split-one` return the current chunk and a reference to the head of the following, i.e. the `cdr` of the last element considered, and keep iterating from that. Here I'm uncertain at what to do.

In addition to that, I've start using the `(if (cond) '() (...))` pattern quite a lot for recurring, so I would be grateful if any seasoned LISPer could comment on how much this is idiomatic and if there are better ways of expressing the same.

Also, the whole point of this exercise is learning, so please don't tell me I should use `string-split` or `regex-split` or the like. I am aware of their existence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr:** See the bottom of the post for my implementation of the function.

As mentioned in Ben Rudgers's answer, lists should not be treated as vectors, as they are not random-access. That means you should not be using numeric indices, list lengths, etc.

### Lists are recursive data structures

Lists are recursive data structures: a list is either an empty list, or else it's a non-empty list which conceptually has a *first* element and a *rest* of the list. For example:

- `()` is an empty list
- `(1)` is a non-empty list with a *first* of 1 and a *rest* of `()`
- `(1 2)` is a non-empty list with a *first* of 1 and a *rest* of `(2)`

To perform an operation across all elements of a list, you make use of this recursive structure:

1. You check whether the list is empty. If so, do the *base case*.
2. Otherwise, do something with the *first* element, then call the same function with the *rest* of the list. This is the *recursive case*.

### Examples of list-processing functions

Here's a simple example, that calculates the sum of a list of numbers:

```
(define (sum lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      0
      (+ (first lst) (sum (rest lst)))))
```

1. *Base case:* if the list is *empty*, the sum is 0.
2. *Recursive case:* if the list is not empty, the sum is the *first* element plus the sum of the *rest* of the list. (Recursive case.)

Another example. Suppose you want to write a function that takes a list of numbers, and returns the square of all of the numbers:

```
(define (square-all lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      empty
      (cons (expt (first lst) 2) (square-all (rest lst)))))
```

1. *Base case:* If the list is *empty*, return an *empty* list.
2. *Recursive case:* If the list is not empty, return a new list where:

   1. the *first* element of the new list is the square of the *first* element of the old list, and
   2. the *rest* of the new list is the "square of all the numbers" of the *rest* of the old list.

As a third example, consider a function where you want to take a list and return all the elements that are numbers:

```
(define (only-numbers lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      empty
      (if (number? (first lst))
          (cons (first lst) (only-numbers (rest lst)))
          (only-numbers (rest lst)))))
```

1. *Base case:* If the list is *empty*, return an *empty* list.
2. *Recursive case:* If the list is not empty, then:

   1. If the *first* element of the old list is a number, return a new list where:

      1. the *first* element of the new list is the *first* element of the old list, and
      2. the *rest* of the new list is only the numbers from the *rest* of the old list.
   2. If the *first* element of the old list is not a number, discard it and return only the numbers from the *rest* of the old list.

### Generalising the above examples

Do you see a pattern? You always check the list for *empty*, and handle the base case if so, and otherwise handle the *first* element along with calling itself with the *rest* of the list. In fact, all three of the functions above fit this pattern:

```
(define (FUNCTION lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      BASE-CASE
      (SOMETHING (first lst) (FUNCTION (rest lst)))))
```

This pattern is called a *right-fold*, or `foldr` as it's called in Racket. All three of the functions above can be written using `foldr` (I use the parameter name `next` to refer to the result of the recursive call, `(FUNCTION (rest lst))`):

```
(define (sum lst)
  (foldr (lambda (element next)
           (+ element next))
         0 lst))

(define (square-all lst)
  (foldr (lambda (element next)
           (cons (expt element 2) next))
         empty lst))

(define (only-numbers lst)
  (foldr (lambda (element next)
           (if (number? element)
               (cons element next)
               next))
         empty lst))
```

This pattern can be used whenever you are writing a function that processes all the elements of a list, one by one. Usually, you would use the element's value to compute the result, but it's not always necessary; for example, you can implement `length` like this:

```
(define (length lst)
  (foldr (lambda (element next)
           (+ next 1))
         0 lst))
```

### Putting all this together

All the above is a very roundabout way to say that the splitting function you're trying to write is also a right-fold operation. It looks like this:

```
(define (split-by lst x)
  (foldr (lambda (element next)
           (if (eqv? element x)
               (cons empty next)
               (cons (cons element (first next)) (rest next))))
         (list empty) lst))
```

Let's break this down:

1. *Base case:* If the incoming list is *empty*, return a list with an empty sublist inside.
2. *Recursive case:* If the incoming list is not empty, consider the *first* element:

   1. If that element is equivalent (`eqv?`) to the splitter, then prepend an empty sublist to the *next* result.
   2. Otherwise, prepend the element to the frontmost sublist of the *next* result.

The code is quite dense, but I intentionally wrote it the way a seasoned Schemer would write it (except that it's more common to write `car`, `cdr`, `null?`, and `'()` instead of `first`, `rest`, `empty?`, and `empty`). It may take you a while to unpack all this information, if you're new to Scheme. Please feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I knew a list is recursively defined, I just couldn't find a proper way to do what I ended up doing with `list-tail`. Believe it or not, my one-week-later solution is very similar to your last snippet, except that I use explicit recursion with a helper. The insight on `foldr` is great.

Comment: For completeness it might be worth mentioning the space complexity of right folding versus left folding.

Comment: @benrudgers Yeah, clarity of code is super duper important, especially for Lisps. As for space complexity of left vs right folds, I wanted to emphasise the _recursive_ aspects of lists, so a discussion of left folds is tangential at best. Iteration doesn't really lend itself as cleanly to mathematical ideas as recursion does.

Comment: @benrudgers Stack won't overflow, except on stackoverflow. At least when we are talking about Racket.

Answer (score 4):

### Style

#### Format

Racket tends to use two space indentation rather than Python's four spaces. This keeps code from indenting too far to the right and because Lisps allow multiple expressions on a single line, reduces the issues with lines becoming uncomfortably long. Keep in mind that "left banana"s [ `(` ] are also there to help the reader.

#### Names

The big ambiguous name is `split`. What does it split? How do I know that it it can't be used on vectors?

The naming is inconsistent: `nextpos` should be `next-pos` per Lisp's conventions. However, `next-position` would be more descriptive. Personally, I'm not a fan `lst` because it looks like `1st` in many typefaces. More importantly I have no idea what a `del` is other than a key on my keyboard. Please give the reader something like `list-of-any` and `delimiter`.

Generally, I find that `first` and `rest` are more readable than `car` and `cdr`. The advantage of the latter pair is their composibility into `caaddr` etc. And if I find myself using that, I consider giving it a name that describes what it represents in the program's business logic, e.g. `(define customer-address caaddr)`.

In the same vein, I agree with your intuition about `(let loop...` using `(define (some-loop-function foo bar baz) ...)` is more clear.

### Code Smell

#### Treating a list as a vector

Your intuition about `list-tail` is also sound.

Lists are ideal for providing sequential access. They are poor for random access with indices because reaching the `k`th element requires following a sequence of pointers from the `first` element until `k` elements have been visited. Likewise, determining the `length` of an `n` element list requires traversing `n` pointers. This can quickly put operations into *O(n^2)* time complexity or worse.

#### Inline Logic

`(loop (let ((...)) (if (...)))` is a hint that `(let loop...)` isn't a particularly clear way to express simple logic.

### An Illustrative alternative

The basic structure of the procedure `split-list` is similar to Racket's built in `(let loop...)` in that there is a recursive call to an inner procedure `my-split` that does the heavy lifting and is initialized with the values from the command line.

Note that `my-split` still takes `target` as an argument. This allowed building it up and testing it before wrapping it between `(define (split-list..)` and the trampoline `(my-split list-of-x target null)`.

```
#lang racket

(define (split-list list-of-x target)

  ;; A predicate to determine to split the list
  (define (split-at? value)
    (not (equal? value target)))

  ;; Inner function to pass around state as accumulator
  (define (my-split list-of-x target accumulator)
    (cond
     ;; Input exhausted
     [(null? list-of-x)
      accumulator]
     [else
      (let-values
        ([(front-list back-list)
          (splitf-at list-of-x split-at?)])    
        (cond
          ;; Input exhausted
          [(null? back-list)
           (append accumulator (list front-list))]
          [else
            (my-split (rest back-list)
                      target
                      (append accumulator (list front-list)))]))]))
  ;; trampoline
  (my-split list-of-x target null))
```

The key element is the use of the library function [`splitf-at`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=splitf#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._splitf-at%29%29) in conjuction with [`let-values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html?q=let-val#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._let-values%29%29). `Splitf-at` performs the task of dividing the list into the part we want to return and the rest of the list which we want to search.

The overall design of the procedure is simplified by a structure based on case analysis and a recursive definition of the inner function.

### Final Thoughts

Finding and working with `splitf-at` and `let-values` is, in my opinion, not something a new racketeer without Lisp experience is likely to do. The only way to see them is to be familiar with Racket's documentation and that takes time.

Comment: For now my rule is "no library functions" at all. Of course there are functions more or less fit for this purpose, but I'm at step 0 and I want to learn as much as possible. I'll just leave nice abstractions for a later moment.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I am not sure what you mean by '*library functions*'.

Comment: I mean non-trivial procedures that I did not write or, at least, I couldn't implement without much thinking. So `map` and `foldr` are ok, but `splitf-at` is not. I'll make the switch to "real world" programming (as in "reuse existing code") once I feel confortable enough with the Racket frame of mind.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Folding and mapping are "library functions" for R5RS Scheme. See **SRFI 1** ( http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-1.html?q=foldr%20#FoldUnfoldMap). That Racket includes them is one of the ways it differs from the standard [as is `foldl` versus `fold` and `foldr` versus `fold-right`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the point of your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your `(if (cond) '() (...))` pattern can be replaced by `(unless (cond) (...))`

The first solution that comes to mind is a recursive one with an accumulator:

```
(define (split lst delim)
  (let loop ([lst lst]
             [accum '(())])
    (if (empty? lst)
      (reverse (map reverse accum))
      (if (equal? delim (first lst))
        (loop (rest lst) (cons '() accum))
        (loop (rest lst) (cons (cons (first lst) (first accum))
                               (rest accum)))))))
```

I'm not very fluent with racket's vocabulary, but looking at http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html there seems enough for a solution in index space if you assume a method called `index-of` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871042/how-do-i-find-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-list-in-racket)

```
(define (split lst delim)
  (let ([pivot (index-of lst delim)])
    (if (not pivot)
      (list lst)
      (cons (take lst pivot)
            (split (drop lst (+ pivot 1)) delim)))))
```

`member` is another tantalizing method, but I can't see an elegant solution using it.

Comment: You can't replace it straight away with `(unless ...` because of `#<void>`, e.g. `(cons 1 (when #f 2))` versus  `(cons 1 (if #f 2 '()))`

Answer (score 1):

Following function may have some ideas:

```
(define (split2 lst del)
  (let loop ((lst lst)(outl '()))        ; start a loop with empty outlist
    (cond
      [(null? lst) (reverse outl)]       ; return outlist if list is empty
      [else (define templist             ; create a list till delimiter
              (for/list ((i lst) 
                         #:break (equal? i del))   ; break on delimiter
                i))
            (loop (drop lst              ; remove initial items from original list
                        (if (>  (length lst) (length templist))   
                            (+ 1(length templist))
                            (length lst)))
                  (cons templist outl)       ; combine templist with outlist
                  )])))                      ; start loop again

(split2 '(a b c x d x e x f) 'x)
(split2 '(0 1 2 0 2 0 3 0) 0)
```

Ouput:

```
'((a b c) (d) (e) (f))
'(() (1 2) (2) (3))
```

Please see my comments in the code above.

Edit: The advantages of above function are:

This method uses relatively simple built-in functions: for/list (along with #:break clause) and drop function.

It follows the task to be done in an iterative manner within the loop:

1. It uses for/list to get items one by one into a list till delimiter is reached. This list is added to final outlist.
2. Drop from initial list those number of initial items (+ 1 for delimiter) and start loop again.

All this results in a relatively small and simple to understand single function program.